# Bootstrap with asp.net forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap in my asp.net form application. I have all the required files in the project:

- bootstrap.min.js
- jquery-2.0.3.min.js
- bootstrap.min.css

When I add a content page in the root directory , the site work perfectly; all the bootstrap features work correctly. But the problem is, when I place content in another folder (eg. webapp/content/default.aspx), the site does not work in IE. On other browsers it displays the content but the features of bootstrap don't work at all.

My scripts:

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

JQuery 2.0.x is not compatable with some of the older browsers.
Use the latest 1.9.x

See http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-2-support-ie6-ie7-ie8/

Comment: isn't ~ a server side concept?

Answer (score 0):

You need a /
as in

```
<script src="/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

To be more complete

1. starting with a slash makes it relative to the root website directory
2. Two periods ../ would make it go up one directory (so ../../ makes it go up two directories ...)
3. ~/ takes you to the root of your project directory.
4. otherwise it is relative to the directory the current file is in. (so js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js is looking for the file in a js subfolder of your current dir.)

Answer (score 0):

```
**Try using the files:**
ie8-responsive-file-warning.js,
html5shiv.js and 
respond.min.js.

Make the Downloads and place the files in js folder.

**Use the paths**

    "@Url.Content("~/patch/file.js")"



     ****Example****


    <head>
        <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy this line! -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="@Url.Content("~/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js")"></script><![endif]-->

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="@Url.Content("~/js/html5shiv.js")"></script>
          <script src="@Url.Content("~/js/respond.min.js")"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        <script src="@Url.Content("~/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js")"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/js/bootstrap.min.js")"></script>

      </head>
```